# SQL Query return latest date with additional information from tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 5 tables and columns pertinent to this query:

- Dogs (ID, CallName, Color, Sex, Chipnumber, BreedID)
- Breed (ID, Name)
- Status (ID, Status, OwnedOnPremises)
- DogsStatus (ID, DogsID, StatusID, StatusDate, Note, ContactsID)
- Contacts (ID, Name)

I am wanting a result of all dogs and their LATEST status. For a test I am using the following records:

- Dogs (251, Tank, Fawn, M, 14410784, 23) (266, Bonnie, Brindle, 14964070, 23)
- Breed (23, Mastiff)
- Status (3, Sold) (4, Given Away) (7, Purchased) (9, Returned)
- DogsStatus (29, 251, 3, 2013-10-12, 5) (39, 251, 9, 2013-11-10, 17) (146, 251, 4, 2014-01-10, 7) (40, 266, 7, 2013-10-30, 1)
- Contacts (1, Person1) (5, Person5) (7, Person7) (17, Person17)

So far I have:

```
SELECT 
    d.CallName, b.Name AS 'Breed', d.Color, d.Sex, d.ChipNumber
FROM 
    Dogs d
JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        DogsID, MAX(StatusDate) as MaxStatusDate 
    FROM DogsStatus 
    GROUP BY DogsID) mds ON mds.DogsID = d.ID
JOIN 
   Breeds b ON b.ID = d.BreedID
```

This will return 2 unique records (1 for Tank and 1 for Bonnie), but whenever I try to get any other of the DogsStatus and/or Status info, I either return only one dog record, or all 3 of Tanks DogsStatus records.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to join the `MaxStatusDate` from your derived table to the `DogsStatus` table.  That allows you to actually restrict it to the most recent status.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 Express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to join your `MaxStatusDate` to the `DogsStatus` table.  That way you will only get the most recent status, in the case where you have multiple statuses.
Something like

```
SELECT 
    d.CallName, b.Name AS 'Breed', d.Color, d.Sex, d.ChipNumber
FROM 
    Dogs d
innner join DogsStatus ds
  ON d.dogsid = ds.dogs_id
JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        DogsID, MAX(StatusDate) as MaxStatusDate 
    FROM DogsStatus 
    GROUP BY DogsID) mds ON mds.DogsID = d.ID
JOIN 
   Breeds b ON b.ID = d.BreedID
   AND mds.maxstatusdate = ds.statusdate
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: The "AND" statement was what I was missing. As a sidenote, I had actually tried this earlier but got skewed results since the StatusDate column for Bonnie was NULL and didn't show as a result from the query making me think my query was incorrectly showing only one record. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 0):

You're close. You just need to go back to the DogStatus table to get that full record. Note that I prefer CTEs for this, but your existing derived table (subquery) approach works just fine, too:

```
With StatusDates As
(

    SELECT 
        DogsID, MAX(StatusDate) as StatusDate 
    FROM DogsStatus 
    GROUP BY DogsID
), CurrentStatus As 
(
    SELECT ds.*
    FROM DogStatus ds
    INNER JOIN StatusDates sd ON sd.DogsID = ds.DogsID AND ds.StatusDate = sd.StatusDate
)
SELECT d.Name, b.Name As Breed, d.Color, d.Sex, d.ChipNumber
    , s.Status, cs.StatusDate, c.Name As ContactName
FROM Dogs d
INNER JOIN CurrentStatus cs ON cs.DogsID = d.ID
INNER JOIN Breed b on b.ID = d.BreedID
INNER JOIN Status s on s.ID = cs.StatusID
INNER JOIN Contact c on c.ID = cs.ContactID
```

You may want to use a LEFT join for some of those, and then change the select list to use coalesce() expressions to clean up the NULLs.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation and quick response. This works as well as the answer below, but the one below seemed a bit simpler to me. I will keep the CTE comment in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this, I'm certain you'll be able to adapt it to your needs:

```
;with x as (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by d.DogsId order by StatusDate desc) as rn
  from Dogs d
  inner join DogsStatus on d.DogsId = ds.DogsId
)
select *
from x
where rn = 1
```